# Best way to pass geolocation to server?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, google-geolocation

Using code similar to http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation, I want to pass latitude and longitude values back to the asp.net server before a page is shown.

I have a SQL database with columns like this:

Cafe Name | Latitude | Longitude

When the user visits CafesNearMe.aspx, I want to list all Cafes within 2km.

How can I pass the front end Lat and Long numbers to the backend so the CafesNearMe.aspx.vb code can use them as query parameters on a SELECT query before any data is shown?

Comment: Just like you pass any other data - through GET request parameters.

Comment: Thanks but won't the backend asp.net vb code fire first and display the list of Cafes before the front end JavaScript has run?

Comment: You can do it asynchronously using AJAX. Load the page -> make AJAX request with geolocation -> server returns data -> javascript renders data.

Comment: Thank you. Currently I have strClsCafeListHTML=fGetCafeList() in the Page Load event in the CafesNearMe.aspx.vb file. How do I delay that from firing until the JavaScript has put the lat and long values into 2 hidden fields?